# Are sans serif fonts easier to read than serif fonts?

Tags: ophthalmology

Origin of claim is http://alexpoole.info/blog/which-are-more-legible-serif-or-sans-serif-typefaces/. At a quarter down the webpage is a more specific claim tendered, with numerous papers cited.

> Sans serif is better at small sizes.

Comment: I think it depends on the medium and dpi. The claim that sans serif fonts are better at small sizes was initially made for screen some years ago when the dpi was relatively low.

Comment: @w3d If that is that answer, please write it as one rather than a comment.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) I've been a bit draconian in putting this question On Hold, sorry, but I think it is worth establishing the ground rules before we get lots of inadequate answers. This question seems to set a very high hurdle for answering. The original source is a thesis which is based on a literature review with lots of references. Why are you skeptical of this? What further evidence would it take to convince you that this is correct or incorrect?

Comment: This would actually be a good question (barring duplicates already) for http://ux.stackexchange.com/